# Is it worth drawing backgrounds manually on canvas?

Tags: android, android-drawable

For example, Holo theme introduced pretty simple EditText background [image: Sample SearchView 9-patch background]

So there is reasonable question - should you export such backgrounds from photoshop, than 9-patch magic and only then add them to project or simply create custom Drawable and draw this background on canvas ?

Yep, i understand that using rasterized resources is more flexible ways and paddings(9-patch is all about stretching and padding)... but this flow kills me: cut, resize, export, resize, export...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case since it's not too complex, though its flow kills(I know that boring workflow) **9-patch** seems to be enough and also responsive, and `custom view` is not so necessary. But if you think about future, e.g you would like to add some other styles to it or styles to the text in it or animating when user types some characters etc, **custom view** seems to be the winner.